# How can I dock a Windows Mobile 6 device and sync it with a local database?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I'm really befuddled by this, I've googled and haven't come across any tutorial or code sample to accomplish this, even a simple tutorial on docking a windows mobile 6 device seems to be hard to come by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do checkout the active sync API if thats what your asking  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457095.aspx

**EDIT** sample codes http://rapi.codeplex.com/discussions/216902

**another link** http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsmobiledev/thread/65a29ea0-af04-4b73-b40e-73f99de4eafc